Custom tool for crewai im trying to build as na alternative to OpenAi API
I have this code which is intended to use YoutubeChannelSearchTool with huggingface open source models, the objective is to create a custom tool to be used as an alternative to OpenAI API enablig the use of the tool without any costs while ensuring results closer to the ones provided by OpenAI, i came up with this code, which mostly the YoutubeChannelSearchTool class with adjustments made to integrate open source models.
from crewai_tools import YoutubeChannelSearchTool
from crewai_tools.adapters.embedchain_adapter import EmbedchainAdapter
from typing import Any, Optional, Type, Dict
from embedchain.models.data_type import DataType
from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel, Field
from langchain_groq import ChatGroq
from embedchain import App
from embedchain.config import AppConfig, BaseEmbedderConfig
from embedchain.embedder.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedder
import chromadb.utils.embedding_functions as embedding_functions
from decouple import config
import os

os.environ["HUGGINGFACE_ACCESS_TOKEN"] = config("HUGGINGFACE_ACCESS_TOKEN")
os.environ["GROQ_API_KEY"] = config("GROQ_API_KEY")

llm = ChatGroq(
    temperature=0,
    groq_api_key=os.getenv("GROQ_API_KEY"),
    model_name="llama3-8b-8192",
    max_tokens=8192,
)

class CustomRagTool(EmbedchainAdapter):
    """A custom RagTool that manages Embedchain configuration internally."""
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str = "Knowledge base",
        description: str = "A knowledge base that can be used to answer questions.",
        summarize: bool = False,
        chunk_size: int = 500,
        vector_store_type: str = "chromadb",
        embedding_model: str = "sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
        **kwargs: Dict[str, Any],  # Explicit type hinting for kwargs
    ):
        hf_config = BaseEmbedderConfig(
            model=embedding_model, 
            api_key=os.getenv("HUGGINGFACE_ACCESS_TOKEN")
            )

        embedder = HuggingFaceEmbedder(config=hf_config)

        app_config = AppConfig()
        self.app = App(config=app_config, embedding_model=embedder)

        super().__init__(embedchain_app=self.app, summarize=summarize)

        api_key = os.getenv("HUGGINGFACE_ACCESS_TOKEN")
        if not api_key:
            raise ValueError("HUGGINGFACE_ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable not set.")

        self.embedding_function = embedding_functions.HuggingFaceEmbeddingFunction(
            api_key=os.getenv("HUGGINGFACE_ACCESS_TOKEN"),
            model_name=embedding_model
            )

class FixedYoutubeChannelSearchToolSchema(BaseModel):
    """Input for YoutubeChannelSearchTool."""
    search_query: str = Field(
        ..., description="Mandatory search query you want to use to search the YouTube Channel's content"
    )

class YoutubeChannelSearchToolSchema(FixedYoutubeChannelSearchToolSchema):
    """Input for YoutubeChannelSearchTool."""
    youtube_channel_handle: str = Field(..., description="Mandatory YouTube channel handle path you want to search")

class CustomYoutubeChannelSearchTool(CustomRagTool):
    name: str = "Search a YouTube Channel's content"
    description: str = "A tool that can be used to semantically search a query from a YouTube Channel's content."
    args_schema: Type[BaseModel] = YoutubeChannelSearchToolSchema

    def __init__(self, youtube_channel_handle: Optional[str] = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        if youtube_channel_handle is not None:
            self.add(youtube_channel_handle)
            self.description = f"A tool that can be used to semantic search a query the {youtube_channel_handle} YouTube Channel's content."
            self.args_schema = FixedYoutubeChannelSearchToolSchema
            
            try:
                if not super().app.db.get_collection(youtube_channel_handle):
                    super().app.db.add_collection(youtube_channel_handle)
            except Exception as e:
                raise RuntimeError(f"Error adding collection: {e}")
            
            embedding_function = embedding_functions.HuggingFaceEmbeddingFunction(
                api_key=os.getenv("HUGGINGFACE_ACCESS_TOKEN"),
                model_name=embedding_model
            )
            collection = super().app.db.get_collection(youtube_channel_handle)
            collection.set_embedding_function(embedding_function) 

    def add(self, youtube_channel_handle: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        if not youtube_channel_handle.startswith("@"):
            youtube_channel_handle = f"@{youtube_channel_handle}"

        kwargs["data_type"] = DataType.YOUTUBE_CHANNEL
        self.app.add(youtube_channel_handle, **kwargs)

    def _before_run(self, query: str, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        if "youtube_channel_handle" in kwargs:
            self.add(kwargs["youtube_channel_handle"])

    def _run(self, search_query: str, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        return super()._run(query=search_query)

# Initialize the tool
yt_search_tool = None
try:
    yt_search_tool = CustomYoutubeChannelSearchTool(
        youtube_channel_handle="@1littlecoder"
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error initializing tool: {e}")

# Verify if __init__ method is being called
if yt_search_tool is not None:
    print("CustomYoutubeChannelSearchTool instance created successfully.")
else:
    print("CustomYoutubeChannelSearchTool initialization failed.")

# Ask a question - add a check if initialization was successful
if yt_search_tool is not None:  
    query = "What are the best Python tutorials on this channel?"
    response = yt_search_tool._run(query)
    print(response)
else:
    print("Tool initialization failed, cannot process query.")

Im getting this error that i can't figure out what's the problem in order to solve it:
Error initializing tool: "CustomYoutubeChannelSearchTool" object has no field "app"
CustomYoutubeChannelSearchTool initialization failed.
Tool initialization failed, cannot process query.

